# Jmeter send requests that are not on my request list

Tags: jmeter

I noticed this when analyzing wireshark. under thread group those requests are:

1. homepage/Account/Login
2. homepage/
3. homepage/LiveAlarm
   and so on.

on wireshark there are some other requests that jmeter sends. but when i test this with browser, that requests wont be send.

after request 2)
HTTP GET /Content/css?v=........... HTTP/1.1\r\n
HTTP GET /Content/cus-css-plugins?v=......-*..... HTTP/1.1\r\n
HTTP GET /images/logo/logo*.._...png HTTP/1.1\r\n
and so on, totally 6 inintended requests are sent. there are not in the sampler list. and not sent when using browser.

the test script is recorded by **blazemeter chrome plugin**.

another unintended request
**HTTP GET /signalr/hubs HTTP/1.1\r\n** is sent by jmeter, but it is **also sent** when using browser.
because it is not in the sample list, the "Accept" field is very different between browser and jmeter. it is another issue. so, should i add this request to jmeter manually and control the fields?

Answer (score 1):

BlazeMeter Chrome Extension generates a JMeter Test Plan with [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configuration element configured to "Retrieve Resources from HTML Files"

[image]

This is normal as it replicates real browser behaviour, real browsers download the HTML content from the response and then execute parallel HTTP Requests to download images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc. and this setting instructs JMeter to behave like a real browser when it comes to these embedded resources handling.

If you open your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) you should see the same requests (just tick "Disable cache" if you don't see them)

[image]

More information: [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)

Comment: thank you for answering the question 1. i got it. what about the second one related with HTTP GET /signalr/hubs HTTP/1.1\r\n request. it is sent by jmeter also browser. but the request is not in my list. so i cant the change the "accept" field. that field is so different than browser

Comment: 1 post - 1 question, your "not on my list" doesn't tell me anything and you're unwilling to share test plan details and network dumps. blind shot - if the request is a result of a [redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) - you can disable it in JMeter and manually add this request as a brand new HTTP Request sampler so you will be able to set the desired [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header value using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)